# Sync keepass database file with cloud storage and multiple users

Tags: sharepoint

The scenario is:
I've been using my keepass file in my onedrive pro folder on my pc.  However, I really need my coworker to have simultaneous access to the file as well.  We have a windows 2003 file server that would work fine (as many other users in our office share their keepass files this way) however I really need mine on me at all times as I need to be able to respond to support issues outside of work hours.

I'm wondering if anyone has any solutions?  My first thought was to store it on the file server and then just manually move it to my onedrive once in a while (the most important logins I would need don't change that often).  I just wanted to check if anyone had a better / more efficient idea?

I saw this page - http://keepass.info/help/kb/trigger_examples.html#dbsync and looked at the "Synchronizing with Dropbox / other PC synchronization software" section but I don't think this would do exactly what I need.  I could be completely wrong, but it seems like that would need to use a single dropbox / onedrive account installed on multiple computers.

We also tried accessing through mapped sharepoint folder (sharepoint online / office 365)  but it didn't seem to work correctly.  If we both had the database open, it wouldn't notify when someone made a change. One user would have to close the file and reopen to see any changes etc...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The link you provide is pretty much what you want - try it and see.

Comment: Thanks...the issue, I believe, is that would require us to be using the same onedrive account, which we're not.

Comment: Also, just curious, why does my post have a -1 next to it?  Did I do something wrong in my post?

Comment: Probably because your post isn't about server administration.  It would be better suited for [superuser](http://superuser.com).

Comment: Well thanks for letting me know, I'll make sure to do that next time.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to suggest two possibilities:

1. Schedule a script that runs on your workstation and copies the keepass file from the server to your onedrive every X minutes.
2. Switch to something like [LastPass Enterprise](https://lastpass.com/enterprise_overview.php) or a competitor with built-in support for multiple users to share passwords.

Good luck!

Comment: This is pretty much what I thought.  I will look into LastPass, thanks for the tip.